# Table size with HTML table code in c#

Tags: c#, html, html-table

Here's my html code inside the C# code

```
tosend = "<p><tr><th>The directory searched:  " + path + " </th><th> between the dates " + fdate + " and  " + ldate + "</th></tr> <br> </p> <tr><th>File Name</th>  <th>File Date</th>  <th>File Hash</th>  <th>Beamer Date</th>  <th>Beamer Hash</th> <th>Status</th></tr>";
for (int i = 0; i < thexfiles.Length; i++)
{ 
    tosend = tosend + "<tr><td>" + thexfiles[i] + "</td><td>" + filedate[i] + "</td><td>" + hashList[i] + "</td><td>" + thexdates[i] + "</td><td>" + beamerHash[i] + "</td><td>" +status[i] + "</td></tr>"; 
}
tosend = "<html><table border="+1+">" + tosend + "</table></html>";
```

and here's a link of how it looks : [Click Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xoejbp9celza2x/Photo%2012-07-2012%2014%2049%2057.png?m)

What I want to do is,

1. I want to extend the first row that it becomes same size of the other rows,
2. as you can see the date rows and the status row's height are too much, i want them to look as a single line, like expand.

That's all I need, so far I have tried normal html width-height etc, I couldn't succeed probably because of wrong notation.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have read the docs on the th tag? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp

Comment: i tried defining their widths and heights, height seems to be working with first row however width does not. ive checked that link already

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<tr>` cannot be a child of `<p>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colspan="100%"` to expand the first row (or use a set number of columns). Beyond that, you simply have too much data that you're trying to squeeze into a small area.  You'll have to chop off the time or remove a column to get the row heights working properly with the data you have.  You could also force the longer columns to give more room to the other columns, but would cause them to wrap as well.

Also note that the `<br></>p>` tags between rows is not valid HTML.

```
tosend = "<tr><th>The directory searched:  " + path + " </th><th colspan='100%'> between the dates " + fdate + " and  " + ldate + "</th></tr><tr><th>File Name</th>  <th>File Date</th>  <th>File Hash</th>  <th>Beamer Date</th>  <th>Beamer Hash</th> <th>Status</th></tr>";

for (int i = 0; i < thexfiles.Length; i++)
{  
    tosend = tosend + "<tr><td>" + thexfiles[i] + "</td><td>" + filedate[i].ToShortDateString() + "</td><td>" + hashList[i] + "</td><td>" + thexdates[i].ToShortDateString() + "</td><td>" + beamerHash[i] + "</td><td>" +status[i] + "</td></tr>";  
}
tosend = "<html><table border="+1+">" + tosend + "</table></html>";
```

Comment: ToShortDateString() is not working

Comment: @tipi - is "filedate[]" holding DateTime objects?  If not, you'll have to truncate the time some other way.

Comment: i used it where i originally added the dates into that string array, it worked, thanks alot. now it looks alot more clean. cheers.

Comment: one last question, when i try to write a string with spaces between them, it just jumps down a row, how can i write in a single row without having it skip  a row ?

Comment: if you want the date explicitly un-broken (single line), then you can use the CSS property: white-space: nowrap;

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but you have two options. 1: your data is wrapping. Set "nowrap" on the TD or TH element. 2: you want the row to span the entire table, set colspan="100%" in the first TR and don't add any more TRs to the row.

Answer (score 0):

As @David said, the construction of HTML is invalid.

- having a "p" and "br" tag in middle of a "tr"
- Also the  tag is missing.

Try to construct the table in this manner. Am putting the HTML code alone

```
 <html>
<body>
<table border=1>
     <tr>
        <th colspan="3">The directory searched</th>
        <th colspan="3"> between the dates </th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>File Date</th>
        <th>File Hash</th>
        <th>Beamer Date</th>
        <th>Beamer Hash</th>
        <th>Status</th>
     </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>thexfiles[i]</td>
        <td>filedate[i]</td>
        <td>hashList[i]</td>
        <td>thexdates[i]</td>
        <td>beamerHash[i]</td>
        <td>status[i]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: colspan solved my problem with first row, however the date column is always returning a string with a space between them so its passing to next line, is there a way to solve that ?

Comment: Try adding a css style to the cells   white-space: nowrap

Answer (score 0):

1. For the cell in first row, use
     <td colspan="5"> 
   if you want it to take place as 5 columns.
2. Use <td nowrap="nowrap"> for the cells you want to have in 1 line.